# Get Column\Field Type from bindingsource

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datasource, bindingsource

Is it possible to get the system type of field in a binding source that uses a Linq data source?

I do not want to use value and do a typeof on it. That would require there be data in the datasource. I want to have a bindingsource and set the datasource to a linq to sql class mapped to a sql view and get the type of a field. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Initially you should set bindingsource.Datasource = typeof(your linq to sql class). If that's not what you mean, you should elaborate.

Comment: I do have it set to a datasource. I guess "uses" may not have been technically accurate verbiage. It's bound now I want the system type of a individual field within the datasource. I realize I can just go to the Linq class and look what type the field is but I want to get the information programically. When you bind controls to a field it gets the information somehow so it must be possible.